# About the boundary of closed set in the unit disk

Tags: general-topology

I recently posted a similar question and I was wondering about this other lemma, also if they state the same thing:

$\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is the closed unit disk.

Let $C \subset \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ a closed set such that $C \cap \mathbb{S^1} = \emptyset$ then there exists a point $z \in \partial C$ such that $|z| <1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the equality $\lvert z\rvert<1$ holds for *every* $z\in\partial C$. To see why, consider the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}C&\longrightarrow&[0,\infty)\\z&\mapsto&\lvert z\rvert.\end{array}$$Since $C$ is closed and bounded, it is compact. Therefore, this function attains a maximum on a $z_0\in C$. But $z_0\notin S^1$. Therefore, if $z\in C$, $\lvert z\rvert\leqslant\lvert z_0\rvert<1$. In particular, since $\partial C\subset C$ (since $C$ is closed), we have$$(\forall z\in\partial C):\lvert z\rvert<1.$$

Comment: what if we remove the hp that $C \cap \mathbb{S^1} = \emptyset$?

Comment: Then the statement is false.